# Load Balancing Mongo DB on GCE instance

Tags: mongodb, google-compute-engine

The default `Click to Deploy MongoDB` for GCE sets up one primary node, one secondary node and one arbiter node. But I can't figure out how mongodb manages to distribute reads between primary and secondary nodes. I have an explicit `external IP` for each node available but I don't want to point my apps to one node or the other ... how do I figure out the load-balancer IP (if there is such a thing) so that I can give that to my app as the mongodb connection url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to connect to a replica set of MongoDB, you will need to specify all hosts in the standard URI connection scheme. For example, to describe a connection to a replica set named `test`, with the following mongod hosts:

```
db1.example.net on port 27017
db2.example.net on port 2500
```

You would use a connection string that resembles the following:

```
mongodb://db1.example.net,db2.example.net:2500/?replicaSet=test
```

For more information about MongoDB's Connection String URI Format, take a look at this [artcile](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/).

Comment: can you please tell me do i have to manually go into instance groups and add all three instances there for load balancing or there is no need of doing that ??

Comment: also from where i will know what is the name of the replica set ??

Comment: also my first instance ip is 192.155.215.789 at port 27017 and second instance ip is 192.155.205.189 and arbiter ip is 192.155.105.18 now and replica set name is test now what will be the url can you please tell me it will be really helpful for me ??